# A fixed <nav> element is appearing behind some page elements

Tags: html, css

I have not changed any opacity properties. It's consistently appearing behind certain h1, p and form elements. But from what I can tell there's nothing that should cause this to happen.

Current CSS:

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
background-color: #404040;
color: whitesmoke;
opacity: 1;
}
```

The same thing is happening to a second mobile navigation div, on the same elements and I don't understand how or why.

Using bootstrap 3.3.5.

Comment: Use `z-index: 1;` or make it 5, 10 whatever till you see it over other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index:1;` or a value greater than 1, until it stacks above all elements.